# Using Autodiscovery (EWS API) with Coldfusion

Tags: java, coldfusion, exchangewebservices

I am attempting to use the Auto Discovery as part of the EWS-JAVA-API in Coldfusion.
The problem is, the AutodiscoverUrl method requires one of the arguments be a callback method.
I figured that I could use Coldfusions dynamic proxy method to achieve this, but I'm having some trouble getting it to work.

The java code I'm trying to convert to Coldfusion is as follows:

```
static class RedirectionUrlCallback implements IAutodiscoverRedirectionUrl {
  public boolean autodiscoverRedirectionUrlValidationCallback( String redirectionUrl) {
    return redirectionUrl.toLowerCase().startsWith("https://");
  }
}
service.autodiscoverUrl("<your_email_address>", new RedirectionUrlCallback());
```

The equivalent code that I have written is:

```
<cfset emailAddress = "" >
<cfset password = "" >
<cfset server_domain = "outlook.office365.com" >

<cfset Version = createObject("java", "microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.ExchangeVersion") >
<!--- Create instance of the MS Exchange Service --->
<cfset ExchangeService = CreateObject("java","microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.ExchangeService").init(Version.Exchange2010_SP1) >

<!--- Create instance of and set the credentials --->
<cfset Credentials = CreateObject("java","microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.WebCredentials") >
<cfset Credentials.init(emailAddress, password) >
<cfset ExchangeService.setCredentials(Credentials) >

<cfset dynamicProxy = createDynamicProxy("autodiscoverRedirectProxy", ["microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.autodiscover.IAutodiscoverRedirectionUrl"] ) >
<cfset validateRedirectionUrlCallback = CreateObject("java","microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.autodiscover.IAutodiscoverRedirectionUrl").init(dynamicProxy) >
<cfset ExchangeService.autodiscoverUrl(emailAddress, validateRedirectionUrlCallback ) >
```

The autodiscoverRedirectProxy is a cfc file which contains the callback as follows:

```
<cfcomponent>
<cffunction 
    name="AutodiscoverRedirectionUrlValidationCallback"
    access="public" 
    returntype="boolean"
    hint="This is going to be used as a dynamic proxy. Used for MS Exchange Autodiscover." >

    <cfargument name="redirectionUrl" type="string" required="true" >
    <cfset var result = false > <!--- init --->
    <cfif left(Arguments.redirectionUrl,8) eq "https://" >
        <cfset result = true >
    </cfif>
    <cfreturn result >
</cffunction>
</cfcomponent>
```

I understand my code is incorrect. And from the error I get back ("Unable to find a constructor for class") I understand why.
But I'm at a loss as to which direction I should take from here, so I'm asking for some ideas.

Answer (score 1):

**Update:**

> `CreateObject("java","microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.autodiscover.IAutodiscoverRedirectionUrl").init(dynamicProxy)`

Sounds like you are using the [example in the docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/10.0/Developing/WSe61e35da8d318518-106e125d1353e804331-7ff9.html), which is a little confusing because it refers to a more complicated scenario than is typical. Most of that example is not applicable here. Do not try and create `IAutodiscoverRedirectionUrl` directly. That is what the dynamic proxy does. Plus, `IAutodiscoverRedirectionUrl` an interface, which does not have a constructor. So it cannot be instantiated with `init()` anyway. Instead, just create the proxy object by passing in the path to your CFC and an array of interface names. Then pass that proxy into the appropriate method:

```
<cfset callbackProxy = createDynamicProxy("path.to.your.AutodiscoverRedirectProxy"
     , ["microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.autodiscover.IAutodiscoverRedirectionUrl"]) >
<cfset ExchangeService.autodiscoverUrl(emailAddress,  callbackProxy) >
```

Also, several of `createObject()` paths are incorrect. The updated code actually causes a "Class Not Found" error with CF11, so I suspect you may be using different code, or possibly a different version. The correct paths for ews-java-api-2.0.jar are:

```
<cfset Version = createObject("java"
    , "microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.enumeration.misc.ExchangeVersion")>
<cfset ExchangeService = createObject("java"
    , "microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.ExchangeService").init(Version.Exchange2010_SP1) >
<cfset Credentials = CreateObject("java"
    , "microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.credential.WebCredentials") >
```

Finally, be sure your function signature matches the one in the interface exactly - including the function name. Skimming the API, the method name should probably be this long mouthful: [autodiscoverRedirectionUrlValidationCallback](https://github.com/OfficeDev/ews-java-api/blob/master/src/main/java/microsoft/exchange/webservices/data/autodiscover/IAutodiscoverRedirectionUrl.java). Not sure whether the `access` level makes a difference, but interface method is `package/protected` whereas the cffunction is `public`. Change as needed.

```
<cffunction 
    name="autodiscoverRedirectionUrlValidationCallback"
    access="public"
    returntype="boolean">

    <cfargument name="redirectionUrl" type="string" required="true" >
....
```

Comment: Thanks for you thoughts Leigh.

Comment: I have tried what you suggested, the response being "autodiscoverUrl method was not found". This happens when the argument to the method is incorrect. I also tried callbackProxy..autodiscoverRedirectionUrlValidationCallback as the argument, the response then being "Element AUTODISCOVERREDIRECTIONURLVALIDATIONCALLBACK is undefined in DYNAMICPROXY".

Comment: Can you update your question with the complete code you tried (including instantiating the javaloader with .jar file paths) and the full error message? I want to to see if I can reproduce it in my environ.

Comment: Also, can you do a cfdump of the `ExchangeService` object?

Comment: I've updated the code. The .jar I'm using was taken from here https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.ews-java-api/ews-java-api/2.0 . I have spent the day looking into this without any luck so far.

Comment: @Steve - Hm... are you positive that is the same code? Throws a totally different error in CF11, "Class not found".   See updated answer.

Comment: Yes, that is definitely not the code throwing a "autodiscoverUrl method was not found" error or you are using a different jar. Using 2.0 the above falls over with this error: "Class not found: microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.ExchangeVersion".

Comment: Yes, the code listed is working for me. I totally agree with your class pathing though. I would have thought, and did try firstly with the class paths that you are using but they did-not/do-not work for me. I have the jar in a folder and have added the path to the jar in the CF Administrator-->CF Class Path.

Comment: Sorry, but there is *absolutely no way* the original paths could work if you really are using ews-java-api-2.0.jar ;-) Open that jar file with a tool like 7-zip. Navigate to the `microsoft.exchange.webservices.data` folder. Notice there is no `ExchangeService.class` file there? Since the class does not exist - there is no way the createObject call could work. So again either you are using different code or a different version of the jar than you think you are using ... one that does contain the path `microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.ExchangeService`

Comment: Oops... that last line should be: *.. one that does contain the path `microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.ExchangeService`*.  Use [this old tip](http://web.archive.org/web/20110625025121/http://bpurcell.org/blog/index.cfm?mode=entry&entry=982) with your ExchangeService object to find out which jar it is really being loaded from ...